# What is a Bonus Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a phrase conforms to a special rule, I call it a Bonus Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Bonus Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Bonus Words™,Not Bonus Words™
ANTENNA,RECEIVER
BAGGAGE,LUGGAGE
DELETED,REMOVED
DISMISS,REJECT
FREEZER,REFRIGERATOR
LAYAWAY,LEASE
MINIMUM,MINIMAL
MONSOON,TYPHOON
OSMOSIS,MITOSIS
RESERVE,WITHHOLD
REVERED,RESPECTED
TEETHED,FANGED
WINNING,LEADING
SELFLESSNESS,BENEVOLENCE
```

Comment: Why all people asking these type of questions gave "Question" in CSV version?

Comment: @SathiReddy Often, the pattern is based on a letter pattern. It can also be based on word meanings, pronunciation, or some other intrinsic value. Offering the CSV lets people more easily examine the words for letter patterns without having to retype the text from the image, which could also introduce transcription errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A bonus word is

> A word whose constituent letter counts follow the Fibonacci sequence (1, 1, 2, 3[, 5]).
> ANTENNA: 1T, 1E, 2A, 3N.
> BAGGAGE: 1B, 1E, 2A, 3G.
> DELETED: 1T, 1L, 2D, 3E.
> DISMISS: 1D, 1M, 2I, 3S.
> FREEZER: 1F, 1Z, 2R, 3E.
> LAYAWAY: 1L, 1W, 2Y, 3A.
> MINIMUM: 1U, 1N, 2I, 3M.
> MONSOON: 1M, 1S, 2N, 3O.
> OSMOSIS: 1M, 1I, 2O, 3S.
> RESERVE: 1S, 1V, 2R, 3E.
> REVERED: 1V, 1D, 2R, 3E.
> TEETHED: 1H, 1D, 2T, 3E.
> WINNING: 1W, 1G, 2I, 3N.
> SELFLESSNESS: 1N, 1F, 2L, 3E, 5S.

Comment: Nice, but why "Bonus"?

Comment: I figured it was just the similarity of BONUS to fiBONAcci.

Comment: Fibonacci's real name was Leonardo Bonacci. The surname Bonacci comes from the first name Bona which is from the Latin Bonus, meaning "good".

Answer (score 6):

A bonus word is one where:

> When you remove all repeating letters, you are left with 2 letters 
>  
>  ANTENNA = TE 
> BAGGAGE = BE 
> DELETED = LT  
> DISMISS = DM 
> FREEZER = FZ 
> LAYAWAY = LW 
> MINIMUM = NU 
> MONSOON = MS 
> OSMOSIS = MI 
> RESERVE = SV 
> REVERED = VD 
> TEETHED = HD 
> WINNING = WG 
> SELFLESSNESS = FN

Answer (score 2):

Bonus Word™ could be

> Word with one letter occurring 3 times and made of 4 different letters.

But then

> Selflessness doesn't fit

Answer (score 1):

A bonus word is a word :

> containing the same 2 vowels and the same 3 consonants, or the same 2 consonants and the same 3 vowels.
> ANTENNA: 2 A, 3 N.
> BAGGAGE: 2 A, 3 G.
> DELETED: 2 D, 3 E.
> DISMISS: 2 I, 3 S.
> FREEZER: 2 R, 3 E.
> LAYAWAY: 2 Y, 3 A.
> MINIMUM: 2 I, 3 M.
> MONSOON: 2 M, 3 O.
> OSMOSIS: 2 O, 3 S.
> RESERVE: 2 R, 3 E.
> REVERED: 2 R, 3 E.
> TEETHED: 2 T, 3 E.
> WINNING: 2 I, 3 N.
> SELFLESSNESS: 2 L, 3 E.

But I think this is only a partial answer. There must be a better rule.

Comment: RECEIVER = 2R, 3E

Comment: That's why I said there must be a better rule.

Comment: Aren't these called Full House Words™?